# Extract pdf files from an email from a specific contact (sender) and different inbox address in outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, attachment

Good morning friends,

Please, I need your help, I have 2 problems:

1.- I wanted to be able to extract pdf files but an email from a specific contact (sender)

2.- I have several inboxes, how could I set another inbox, but not the one that comes by default - here I tried the following "Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder (onothermail@gmail.com)" but it did not work for me

Thank you very much in advance

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
   '// Declare your Variables
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim AtmtName As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient

   '// Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objOwner = olNs.CreateRecipient("secondMail@gmail.com")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner)
   
    
    

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Unity\Desktop\adjuntos\"
    
    Filter = "[Unread] = True"
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)

   '// Loop through backwards
    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items(i)

        DoEvents

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
            If Item.SenderEmailAddress = "senderx@gmail.com" Then

                For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                    AtmtName = FilePath & Atmt.FileName
                    If ((InStr(Atmt.DisplayName, ".jpg") Or InStr(Atmt.DisplayName, ".zip") Or InStr(Atmt.DisplayName, ".PDF") Or InStr(Atmt.DisplayName, ".pdf"))) Then

                        Atmt.SaveAsFile FilePath & "\" & Atmt.DisplayName
              
                    End If
                    Item.UnRead = False
                Next
            End If
            
        End If
    Next

    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set Items = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It seems additionally you need to check the sender's email address of the item. The [MailItem.SenderEmailAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailaddress) property returns a string that represents the email address of the sender of the Outlook item.

```
Sub SetFlagIcon() 
 Dim mpfInbox As Outlook.Folder 
 Dim obj As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim i As Integer 
 Set mpfInbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test") 
 ' Loop all items in the Inbox\Test Folder 
 For i = 1 To mpfInbox.Items.Count 
   If mpfInbox.Items(i).Class = olMail Then 
     Set obj = mpfInbox.Items.Item(i) 
     If obj.SenderEmailAddress = "someone@example.com" Then 
       'Set the yellow flag icon 
       obj.FlagIcon = olYellowFlagIcon 
       obj.Save 
     End If
   End If
 Next 
End Sub
```

However, iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea. Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
  Also you may use the `AdvancedSearch` method of the Application class helpful. See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.

2. Use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method instead. It returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and thanks for the documentation, I will also try the recommendations.

Comment: How would I have to set up to be able to download from my second inbox, but it does not allow me to configure it
Set objOwner = olNs.CreateRecipient ("origin2@gmail.com")
Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder (objOwner)

but it didn't work for me

Comment: Do you have another account configured in Outlook?

Comment: Yes, that is a second email

Comment: There is no need to use the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method then. It is for shared accounts/folders. What you really need is the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the Store class.

Comment: I tried with Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder("msecondMail@gmail.com")                   
 Run-time error '13' occurred
types do not match

Comment: You need to use the method which belongs to the Store class, not Namespace.

Comment: I got the same error message above, I'm doing something wrong              Dim oStore As Outlook.Store

 
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = oStore.GetDefaultFolder("mysecondmail@gmail.com")

Comment: The `GetDefaultFolder` method accepts one of the [OlDefaultFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.oldefaultfolders) values, not email addresses.